# Seeing double for username info boxes in macOS Safari

Tags: bug, user-interface, safari

If a picture is worth a thousand words, look at these thousand or so words.

What’s up with the seemingly doubled user info for these three items on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)? I am using plain old [macOS Monterey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (12.5.1) and Safari 15.6.1. No extensions or user scripts are in place.

It seems to show up when I load Super User in Safari, do something else on my desktop so Safari is no longer the main application and then go back to Safari. I am never hiding the application and there is only one tab.

That said, perhaps the embedded ads on the page at the time caused some kind of “craziness” on the pay? Modern ad-tech tends to overstep boundaries at times. Would explain the trickiness in trying to recreate this on my side.

> [image]